# access Error table in msi

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-installer

Basically I am trying to make a localized copy of an existing English msi file.
If I rebuild the MSI with proper wxl file n code page it takes a long time, and I need my installer in more than 25 languages. I am able to access all other local strings like text on controls n all but I couldn't find the way to change the error table.

I tried exporting all tables of my MSI using Orca but there was no "error table".

I also tried the following code to access Error Table but it fails.

---

```
      //string strControlName = "Back";
      //string sql = String.Format("SELECT Text FROM Control WHERE Control='{0}'", strControlName);
      //ABOVE SQL EXECUTES SUCCESSFULLY

      string sql = "SELECT Error FROM Error";
      view = database.OpenView(sql);// THROWS EXEPTION AND FAILS.
      view.Execute(null);
      record = view.Fetch();
      if (record != null)
      {
          retVal = record.get_StringData(1);
      }
      System.Console.WriteLine("retVal = " + retVal);
```

---

I referred to [MSDN Error Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368554(v=VS.85).aspx) for above.
Please suggest ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add an Error table to the MSI yourself, the Windows Installer falls back to it's own error messages (that follow the user language choice, IIRC). If you want an Error table, you have to add it yourself.