# Access denied when run the wix installer with administrator permission SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created a windows installer using wixtoolset but when I install it says access denied although I ran the installer with administrator permission. I have attached the access denied popup image and logs

```
Property(C): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID = 1
=== Logging stopped: 5/8/2021  12:06:41 ===
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708 
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Product: Abc -- Installation failed.
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Windows Installer installed the product. Installation success or error status: 1603.
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (7C:3C) [12:06:41:423]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
```

[image]

Any clue why this would happen

Comment: Does this happen on a clean test virtual?

Comment: I think WiX creator Rob Mensching chose to remove the embedded Error table inside each MSI file because he prefers [the "fallback solution" described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273365/129130). This sounds rational since this seems to yield localized (translated) error messages. There are probably other reasons that make sense as well - I don't have a full overview.

Answer (score 0):

***Logging***: You might want to create a [**verbose log with debugging information**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130):

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log
```

***Custom Actions***: Are there any custom actions in your MSI? If so, try to disable them by setting the condition for them to run to 0 in the MSI (use Orca to tweak the MSI for testing) or compile a version of the MSI without custom actions. Just to test.

***Anti-Virus***: It could be that your MSI has been quarantined by your anti-virus [as discussed here](https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/Access-to-the-Temp-Directory-Denied/td-p/145612). Did you try to disable anti-virus before running your MSI?

***Other Ideas***: There are many possible causes. It can be weird interactions such as software installed on the box that causes problems - try on a clean machine or virtual first.

- [**There is a long list of "ideas" here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (section *"Generic Tricks? - Consumer issues, failure to install setup.exe"*).
- [**Here is another version of the setup checklist**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369648/bitvise-sh-client-installation-error-createdirectory-failed-windows-error-5/60374125#60374125) (slightly longer actually, and easier to find - the other answer is chaotic).

Some quick questions:

- Is this a corporate machine with policies of all kinds?
- Do you have any disk space issues?
- Do you work off a network drive?

Comment: I am providing a [link](https://github.com/pyxll/pyxll-installer/blob/master/templates/Product.wxs) of wxs file .

Is this a corporate machine with policies of all kinds?(Yes)
Do you have any disk space issues?(No)
Do you work off a network drive?(No)

Comment: I did run with your logging recommended way but the response was same

Comment: I see you try to make a package that can run without admin rights. [Please check these restrictions for packages to function in this scenario](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/single-package.html).